# get filepath in Jdeveloper Extension development

Tags: jdeveloper

I am developing a Jdev extension. The main aim is to change the file contents under selection (applying some rules on the code). I used the FirstSample sample extension to build my application.

I want the filepath of the file i right clicked to invoke the extension

i was able to get the project path using the below code

```
context.getProject().getURL()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context.getElement().getLongLabel()
```

provides the file path

Answer (score 0):

I would say that context.getNode().getURL() is the proper way to get a path of the selected node.
Please see 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13403/oracle/ide/Context.html